# Finding and counting strings using multiple index vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a character array (this can also be stored as a cell array if more useful) (`list`) and wish to tally the number of substring occurrences against two different indexes held in two separate variables `type`  and `ind`.

```
list =
C C N N C U C N N N C N U N C N C

ind =
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 

type = 
15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
```

*No spaces exist in the character array - added for clarity.*

Using the above example, the desired output would tally all instances of unique letters in `list`, for each `ind` and for each `type` - creating three columns (for C/N/U), each with 4 rows (for each ind) - per type. This is done using the order in which the entries in each array appear.

Desired output of above example (the labels are added for clarity only):

```
            Type 15              Type 16
   Ind  C      N      U      C      N      U
    1   2      0      0      1      1      0
    2   1      2      0      0      1      0
    3   1      1      1      1      1      1
    4   0      1      0      1      1      0
```

I am only aware of how to do this with a single index (using `unique`, `full` and `sparse`).

How can I bet go about doing this with a dual index?

Comment: Does `list` always contain only _two_ letters?

Comment: No - as shown in this example, it always contains three (N,C and U).

Comment: Sorry, I had only seen `C` and `N`:-)

Comment: Then `accumarray` seems to be the best approach

Comment: @AnnaSchumann I added a solution using `crosstab`, seems to be the most appropriate for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility could be to transform your letters to doubles by substracting e.g. `-64` to map the number **3** to the letter **C**.

Then you can use `unique` with `'rows'` and `'stable'`, to get the following result:

```
list = char('CCNNCUCNNNCNUNCNC')
ind = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4]
type = [15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16]

data = [type(:) ind(:) (list(:) - 64)]
[a,~,c] = unique(data,'rows','stable')
occ = accumarray(c,ones(size(c)),[],@numel)

output = [a, occ]
```

---

```
output =

    15     1     3     2
    15     2    14     2
    15     2     3     1
    15     3    21     1
    15     3     3     1
    15     3    14     1
    15     4    14     1
    16     1    14     1
    16     1     3     1
    16     2    14     1
    16     3    21     1
    16     3    14     1
    16     3     3     1
    16     4    14     1
    16     4     3     1
```

If you have the **Statistics Toolbox** you should consider using [**`grpstats`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/grpstats.html).

---

If you don't mind a mind twisting output then [**`crosstab`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/crosstab.html.html) is the far easiest solution:

```
output = crosstab(type(:),ind(:),list(:)-64)

%// type in downwards, ind to the right
output(:,:,1) =   %// 'C'

     2     1     1     0
     1     0     1     1


output(:,:,2) =   %// 'N'

     0     2     1     1
     1     1     1     1


output(:,:,3) =  %// 'U'

     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0
```

The following one liner looks close like your desired output:

```
output2 = reshape(crosstab(ind(:),list(:)-64,type(:)),4,[],1)

output2 =

     2     0     0     1     1     0
     1     2     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1     0
```

---

Also in this toolbox, you can find the [**`tabulate`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) function which offers another option in combination with `accumarray`:

```
[~,~,c] = unique([type(:) ind(:)],'rows','stable')
output = accumarray(c(:),list(:),[],@(x) {tabulate(x)} )
```

[image]

Which also allows the following output:

```
d = unique([type(:) ind(:) list(:)-64],'rows','stable')
output2 = [num2cell(d(:,[1,2])) vertcat(output{:})]

output2 = 

    [15]    [1]    'C'    [2]    [    100]
    [15]    [2]    'N'    [2]    [66.6667]
    [15]    [2]    'C'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [15]    [3]    'U'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [15]    [3]    'C'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [15]    [3]    'N'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [15]    [4]    'N'    [1]    [    100]
    [16]    [1]    'N'    [1]    [     50]
    [16]    [1]    'C'    [1]    [     50]
    [16]    [2]    'N'    [1]    [    100]
    [16]    [3]    'U'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [16]    [3]    'N'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [16]    [3]    'C'    [1]    [33.3333]
    [16]    [4]    'N'    [1]    [     50]
    [16]    [4]    'C'    [1]    [     50]
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. +1 for `crosstab` and the one-liner. Very concise and simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `accumarray`:

```
Output = accumarray([type',ind'],list');
```

Could be you need to convert `type` and `list` to numbers first using `str2num` and then use `accumarray` and transform the result back to numbers using `num2str`.

Comment: I'm having problems implementing this approach due to the data types at hand. I've tried to simplify this by using simple vectors for `ind` and `type` that contain purely numerical data. However 'list' must either be a cell array or character array. `str2num` returns an empty cell array when I attempt to convert it for use with `accumarray`.